# Marginal likelihood and profile likelihood: Gaussian case

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, marginal-distribution, profile-likelihood

Consider a model such that the log-likelihood function of a $n$-dimensional parameter $\theta$ is given by (can be approximated by)
$$\tag{1}
L(\theta)=L(\widehat \theta) -\frac12 (\theta - \widehat \theta)^{\top}I(\widehat \theta)(\theta - \widehat \theta),
$$
where $I(\theta)$ is the observed Fisher information.

The marginal likelihood $L_i (\theta_i)$ for the $i$-th parameter reads, in this case
$$\tag{2}
L_i(\theta_i)=L(\widehat\theta)-\frac{(\theta_i-\widehat\theta_i)^2}{2\left(I(\widehat \theta)^{-1}\right)_{ii}}.
$$
The profile likelihood for the $i$-th component of $\theta_i$ reads
$$
\mathrm{PL}(\theta_i)=\max_{\theta_{-i}}L(\theta_i,\theta_{-i}),
$$
where $\theta_{-i}$ denotes the vector with all components of $\theta$ except the $i$-th.

In case the likelihood can be written as (1), does the PL coincide with (2), or is close to it?

Comment: Yes they coincide in the gaussian case